# IndentationError: unexpected unindent [TELEGRAM BOT, PYTHON]

Tags: python, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    elif(message.text == " Советы по ИБ"):
    b = random.choice(spisok.sp)
    b1 = b['advice']
    b2 = b['title']
    @bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'''{b1} n/ {b2}''')


        
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Я так понимаю, что нужно закрыть блок. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Для начала прислать код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: elif(message.text == " Советы по ИБ"):
        b = random.choice(spisok.sp)
        b1 = b['advice']
        b2 = b['title']
        @bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'''{b1} n/ {b2}''')


            
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Comment: Зачем вы сюда декоратор впихнули `@` ? `@bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'''{b1} n/ {b2}''')`

Comment: Упс, да, спасибо, не заметил. Устал сильно.